# Generic NSFetchedResultsController with generic NSFetchRequest results in an error

Tags: ios, swift, generics, core-data, nsfetchrequest

When trying to set up a generic fetched results controller I get `Cannot convert value of type 'NSFetchRequest<T>' to expected argument type 'NSFetchRequest<_>', Insert ' as! NSFetchRequest<_>` when initializing the controller.

```
fileprivate var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<T>!

    guard let request: NSFetchRequest<T> = T.fetchRequest() as? NSFetchRequest<T> else {
        assertionFailure("Can't set up NSFetchRequest")
        return
    }
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: key, ascending: ascending)]
    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: dataStore.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch let error {
        DDLogError("Error fetching entities: \(error)")
    }
```

Anyone knows what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For FRC you should explicitly specify that it have a type T.

Also, there is not enough of context from your code snippet, so it's unclear how did you define this class. However, here is how I think it should look like:

```
import CoreData
class Model<T> where T: NSManagedObject {

    fileprivate var context: NSManagedObjectContext! // assume that somewhere during initialization we setting context

    fileprivate lazy var fetchedResultscontroller: NSFetchedResultsController<T> = { [weak self] in
        guard let this = self else {
            fatalError("lazy property has been called after object has been descructed")
        }
        guard let request = T.fetchRequest() as? NSFetchRequest<T> else {
            fatalError("Can't set up NSFetchRequest")
        }

        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "key", ascending: true)]
        let tmp = NSFetchedResultsController<T>(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: this.context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        return tmp
    }()
}
```